# hapi fhir jpa: resources not found

Tags: hapi, hapi-fhir

I'm trying to deploy an spring-boot service using `hapi-fhir-jpa`.

Currently, I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: The validated object is null
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:347) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:225) ~[commons-lang3-3.11.jar:3.11]
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:207) ~[commons-lang3-3.11.jar:3.11]
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.noNullElements(Validate.java:559) ~[commons-lang3-3.11.jar:3.11]
    at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.RestfulServer.setResourceProviders(RestfulServer.java:809) ~[hapi-fhir-server-5.3.3.jar:na]
    at ca.uhn.fhir.spring.boot.autoconfigure.FhirAutoConfiguration$FhirRestfulServerConfiguration.initialize(FhirAutoConfiguration.java:160) ~[hapi-fhir-spring-boot-autoconfigure-5.3.3.jar:na]
    at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.RestfulServer.init(RestfulServer.java:1285) ~[hapi-fhir-server-5.3.3.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

My related hapi-fhir configuration is:

```yaml
hapi:
  fhir:
    version: R4
    supported_resource_types:
     - Patient
     - Observation
    server:
      path: /fhir/*
    rest:
      server-name: hapi-fhir-spring-boot-sample-server-jersey
      server-version: 1.0.0
      implementation-description: Spring Boot Jersey Server Sample
      default-response-encoding: json
      e-tag-support: enabled
      default-pretty-print: true
    validation:
      enabled: true
      request-only: true
```

My `pom.xml` dependencies are:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-fhir-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-fhir-jaxrsserver-base</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-fhir-validation-resources-dstu3</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-fhir-structures-dstu3</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi-fhir-jpaserver-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

In order to start my service I run `mvn clean spring-boot:run`.

Any ideas?